# How can I export my PuTTY configuration?

Tags: windows, putty

How can I export all my settings in PuTTY (e.g. Saved Sessions Configurations) from one machine and import them on another computer?

Both machines are running Windows.

Comment: [See answer on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13023920/2415524)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Simply export the registry key at `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\SimonTatham` as a `.reg` file, and double-click it on another machine to merge it.

[image]